# Setting up Polymer with Jekyll?

Tags: polymer, jekyll

I'm trying to use Polymer with a Jekyll site, but I can't figure out how to get things set. I downloaded and can run the Polymer Starter Kit. Polymer has the page contents in the `app` directory, but if I try to set up and run Jekyll from this folder, I get a load of errors because the Polymer `index.html` can't find the resources (because the root directory is different).

What is the correct way to set-up and structure for Jekyll and Polymer to work together?

Comment: While more complex than you need, the polymer docs use Jekyll + polymer. I'd browse around that source to see what we did: https://github.com/polymer/docs.

Comment: Thanks. I still haven't gotten the docs running locally, but that's definitely a good resource to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came back to this, and things are much improved since last summer. I made a gulpfile based on that for the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/gulpfile.js) (1.2.3). But I changed the behavior of the `default` and `serve` tasks to run Jekyll serve and build in the shell:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var argv = require('yargs').argv;

gulp.task('jekyllbuild', function(done) {
  return spawn('bundle', ['exec', 'jekyll', 'build'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
      .on('close', done);
});

// Build production files, the default task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function(cb) {
  // Uncomment 'cache-config' if you are going to use service workers.
  runSequence(
    'jekyllbuild',
    ['ensureFiles', 'copy', 'styles'],
    'elements',
    ['images', 'fonts', 'html'],
    'vulcanize', // 'cache-config',
    cb);
});

gulp.task('serve', function(done) {
  if (argv.port) {
    return spawn('bundle', ['exec', 'jekyll', 'serve', '--port=' + argv.port], { stdio: 'inherit' })
        .on('close', done);
  } else {
    return spawn('bundle', ['exec', 'jekyll', 'serve'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
        .on('close', done);
  }
});
```

Using BrowserSync would have a much cleaner effect, but this is a simple way to get Jekyll functionality and the benefit of vulcanization for production. (Note that you also have to install the `yargs` package to handle port specification.) My whole gulpfile is [here](https://github.com/jtebert/jekyll-polymer/blob/146862200dd5b3c743118fa66e86279e296b0abd/gulpfile.js).

Answer (score 1):

Reading polymer started kit [readme.md paragraph development workflow](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/README.md#development-workflow) you learn that :

`gulp serve` is made for development phase and `gulp` makes a build of your application, ready to be deployed on a web server.

Just copying what you've downloaded from github on a web server will not work `as is`, because `gulp serve` is more complex than this. Read the `gulpfile.js` and you will see all what is done by the `gulp serve` command.

You need to do a `gulp` and you then can deploy what is generated in the `dist` folder. This will work in a jekyll site.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate [gulp-jekyll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jekyll) in your gulp build process. I'd also consider watching changes in your browser-sync to automatically generate html files on change. Vulcanization process should be done only when you are deploying.