# Jekyll + Polymer + Vulcanize - How does this work?

Tags: polymer, jekyll, bower, polymer-1.0, vulcanize

I just started integrating Polymer into my Jekyll environment.
Essentially, I created a bower.json file in my Jekyll root that calls for followingdepencendies:

```
...
],
 "dependencies": {
"iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#^1.0.0",
"paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.1",
"polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

After running `bower install` in my Jekyll root, I ge the bower_components folder with all Polymer packages I requested. In my Jekyll template's `head.html`, I include

```
<link rel="import" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
 ...
```

in order to integrate the desired Polymer packages. I run `jekyll serve` to create and see the page. So far so good.

However, I feel this may produce a long loading time for my page, not? 
I'm, almost sure Google's own website speed test would ask me to reduce the number of http calls. As I discovered, Polymer provides a package named `vulcanize` to combine the http requests into one: https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize

Honestly, I have no clear idea how to integrate this into my process. I've seen some docs that talk about `grunt` but honestly I have no idea about that.

**Can anyone provide a small input on how to compress my Polymer featured Jekyll page** (html, html calls, css...) **?** Thanks!

Comment: get the 'polymer starter kit' from github and then dig into the gulp task for 'serve '  vs 'serve prod'   . the prod task will output vulcanize task to ./dist and you can look into details of whats going on.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could someone provide an example of using vulcanize with gulp and Jekyll+Polymer? It seems this topic is little unsolved. [https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-assets/issues/155](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-assets/issues/155)

Comment: Re 'jekyll-polymer' requirement. Why do you even need jekyll for static stuff when the gulp integration with the PSK covers hosting/serving static pages.  take the git/PSK project at face value and what's 'in there'.  you may conclude that jekyll's redundant with polymer & PSK??  I've used minimal git-hub pages and jekyll stuff in the past and would not really consider it with new polymer projects because gulp covers whatever i would have needed jekyll for.  They are trying to make 'vulcanize' step just work so that all you have to do to wrap a  gulpTask.start command for your web host.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and finally got around to a solution, in case you're still working on this. (Originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793352/setting-up-polymer-with-jekyll/35579108#35579108))

I used Gulp, copying the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/gulpfile.js) (1.2.3). I used the `package.json`, `tasks/` directory, and modified `gulpfile.js.` I changed the behavior of the `default` and `serve` tasks to run Jekyll serve and build in the shell. I also changed directory references in the gulpfile to vulcanize the files in `app/_site/` instead of `app/`.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var argv = require('yargs').argv;

gulp.task('jekyllbuild', function(done) {
  return spawn('bundle', ['exec', 'jekyll', 'build'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
      .on('close', done);
});

// Build production files, the default task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function(cb) {
  // Uncomment 'cache-config' if you are going to use service workers.
  runSequence(
    'jekyllbuild',
    ['ensureFiles', 'copy', 'styles'],
    'elements',
    ['images', 'fonts', 'html'],
    'vulcanize', // 'cache-config',
    cb);
});

gulp.task('serve', function(done) {
  if (argv.port) {
    return spawn('bundle', ['exec', 'jekyll', 'serve', '--port=' + argv.port], { stdio: 'inherit' })
        .on('close', done);
  } else {
    return spawn('bundle', ['exec', 'jekyll', 'serve'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
        .on('close', done);
  }
});
```

Using BrowserSync would have a much cleaner effect, but this is a simple way to get Jekyll functionality and the benefit of vulcanization for production. (Note that you also have to install the `yargs` package to handle port specification.) My whole gulpfile is [here](https://github.com/jtebert/jekyll-polymer/blob/146862200dd5b3c743118fa66e86279e296b0abd/gulpfile.js).